# Is there a shortcut to swap/reorder parameters in visual studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide, code-editor

I have a common issue when working with code in the IDE:

```
string.Concat("foo", "bar");
```

and I need to change it to:

```
string.Concat("bar", "foo");
```

Often I have several of these that need to be swapped at once.  I would like to avoid all the typing.  Is there a way to automate this?  Either a shortcut or some sort of macro would be great if I knew where to start.

Edit: changed to string.Concat to show that you can't always modify the method signature.  I am only looking to change the order of the params in the method call, and nothing else.

Answer (score 5):

`<Ctrl>` + `<Shift>` + `<t>` will transpose two words, so it would work in your case. Unfortunately I don't see this working (without multiple presses) for functions with larger parameter lists...

Comment: This comes close, but unfortunately doesn't work for comma delimited params.  I end up with something like (,"foo" "bar") or (,foo""bar")  perhaps its just the quotes that throw it off.  But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of code with this function:

```
SetInt(comboBox1.Value + 1, "paramName", ...
SetInt(comboBoxOther.Value, "paramName", ...
```

And I needed to swap only the first two parameters;

I ended up using some text editor with regular expression management (like [Scite](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html)), and using this one saved me hours:

```
Find: SetInt(\([.a-z0-9]+[ + 1]*\), \("[a-z0-9]+"\)
Replace: SetInt(\2, \1
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an extension that does exactly this one thing.

It describes itself as

> Allows arguments (or other comma separated lists contained in
> brackets, braces, etc.) to be shifted left and right.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.shifter

Answer (score -1):

Resharper once again shows superior features over Visual Studio. Since there is no definitive answer and I came here by a Google search, I felt the need to give this information:

Resharper has a refactoring feature called [Change Signature refactoring](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html) and this works seamlessly together with the shortcuts for [Rearrange code elements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html)﻿.

1. You can simply select the parameter you want to move, then do <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt + Left/Right</kbd>
2. Once done, you can then press <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> and choose `Apply Change Signature refactoring...`